# Specific namecoin address in merged mining

Tags: namecoin, p2pool, merged-mining

I want to do merged mining with P2Pool, and I want any generated namecoins to go to a specific namecoin address in my wallet. I haven't seen a way to configure this in P2Pool or namecoind, and Google's turned up no hits. It seems as though it's either too obvious for anybody to mention in any guides, or like I'm the only one who wants to do this. If the latter, then why does nobody want this and why should I not do this?

Comment: Good question, i also want to do this but i dont seem to find any info about it.

Comment: yeah it look interesting! I assume slush. Anyway, to always have your namecoin sending funds you would need to write a good bit of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with p2pool at least for the coins are 'merged' mining you cannot reconfigure them to go to any other account except for the default account of that wallet.  However  you may be able to work around this in one of the following ways depending on your coding ability.

**Monitor P2Pool logs and trigger script**

Watch the p2pool logs and when a block is found trigger a script.
This can be achieved using swatch (linux tool for watching logs files) and looking for merged blocks that appear in /path/to/p2pool/data/bitcoin/log  (cant find the example merged block right now will edit later to include)  so in this instance what you would do is use this command:  swatch -t /path/to/p2pool/data/bitcoin/log  and create a ~/.swatchrc in your home directory with something like this:

```
watchfor /SHARE|BLOCK/
    exec echo "P2Pool Event:\n\n$_\n" | python ~/pyPushBullet/pushbullet_cmd.py 6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx60993c note xxxxxx"P2Pool Notification" "$_"
```

Im using push bullet to send notifications on share and block notifications.  however in your case you would want to craft a script to check the block itself for merged outputs.

**Wallet Notify**

Most Crypto Clients now let you configure an action for

```
  -blocknotify=<cmd>     Execute command when the best block changes (%s in cmd is replaced by block hash)
  -walletnotify=<cmd>    Execute command when a wallet transaction changes (%s in cmd is replaced by TxID)
  -alertnotify=<cmd>     Execute command when a relevant alert is received (%s in cmd is replaced by message)
```

[Courtesy Off The Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin)

again in the same vein as the first optin you could  create a script that is triggered on wallet notify for the Nnamecoin wallet and move the coins from the default addreaa to you chosen address.

Comment: Thanks. Another option would be to edit the wallet and change the default address. I'd need to check if the default NMC address changes when it receives coins; I think it does, so I'd still need to use one of these.

Comment: Daniel have you got an resources with info on editing the wallet, its not something I've done before....

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there's a few things about merged mining. The pool must offer it for it to work. I use slosh pool which does it and they mine both bit and name coin; with them, the pool automatically does it and there aren't any extra settings other than the basic login into the miner and pool. It keeps going until you reach an amount you have set and then it deposits it into your wallet. With your pool, it could be different.

**Brief explanation:**

- pool must offer merged mining for you to merge mine.
- I use slosh pool
- They automatically do both and deposit into your wallet after you reach the amount you
- yours might be different

Comment: I guess you mean _slush_ pool?

Comment: BTCGuild offers merged mining as well.

Comment: I assume slush. Anyway, to always have your namecoin sending funds you would need to write a good bit of code. The tl;dr of it is this: you need to change the block coinbase to have it directed to the wallet of your choice. And even the I am not completely sure that would work. I mean in theory it should... But right now nmc needs tlc just need to get their code fixed Amd here's whyhttp://dot-bit.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1295&start=10

Answer (score 0):

I assume slush. Anyway, to always have your namecoin sending funds you would need to write a good bit of code. The tl;dr of it is this: you need to change the block coinbase to have it directed to the wallet of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I also use p2pool to do merged mining. I have searched the code extensively and do not believe it is possible to mine to an address. Instead, as another answerer suggested, the block reward goes to the default account associated with your namecoind.

Answer (score -2):

Probally just goes to default NMC address

Comment: A bit more certainty would be great. Unless you can back this up with personal experience or a reference, a guess isn't very useful.

Comment: I hate to say it, but at very least tell us why? Or you can always make a comment below the post too